# how to split the sentence that is rendered from html using query select all

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

```js
(async () => {
  let browser, page;
  let url = "https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/nyc/search/?query=cars";
   browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
   page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
   console.log("scraping...");
   let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let cars = [];
           if (
               document.querySelectorAll(
                'div[class="fome6x0j tkqzz1yd aodizinl fjf4s8hc f7vcsfb0"]'
               )
           ) {
               document.querySelectorAll(
               'div[class="fome6x0j tkqzz1yd aodizinl fjf4s8hc f7vcsfb0"]'
              )
          .forEach((element) => {
              let prices = element.querySelectorAll(
              'span[class="d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz qv66sw1b"]'
            );
            let listings = element.querySelectorAll(
              'span[class="a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7"]'
            );
                    
          

            for (let i = 0; i < addLists.length; i++) {
              const car = {
                price: prices[i].innerText,
                listing: listings[i].innerText,
                sentence1:''
                sentence2:''
              };

              cars.push(car);
            }
          });
      }

      return cars;
    });

    console.log(data);
  } 
})();
```

how to split the sentence that is rendered using listings , listings is the list of facebook add titles, I tried using split() function but it doesn't work,is there anyway that I can split that sentence and store it in sentence1 and sentence2

[image]

Comment: Can you post more code? We can't really tell what's happening in your html or what you are getting in that 'addLists'

Comment: yeah ok , wait i will do that ..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to split or what info you mean to extract. The current code won't work because `prices`, `listings` aren't defined. Furthermore, `if (document.querySelectorAll("foo"))` is always true even if no nodes were found, so there's no need for that code. Can you clarify your intent and show the output you want to get? Thanks.

Comment: i have made the changes ,in the output you can see listings, need split that sentence and store each word seperately

Comment: I still don't see any `sentence1` or `sentence2` in your expected output, which should be [text, not a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) please. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @ggorlen actually need the split the sentence returned by listing(2014 audi a6) as sentence1:2014 and sentence2 : audi

Comment: So `const [sentence1, sentence2] = listings[i].innerText.split(/\s+/)`? This seems like a simple string problem having nothing to do with Puppeteer, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this a try.

```
(async () => {
  let browser, page;
  let url = 'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/nyc/search/?query=cars';

  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 500 });
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 60000 });

    let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let cars = [];

      if (document.getElementsByClassName('sonix8o1')) {
        Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('sonix8o1')).forEach(element => {
          let text = element.innerText;

          if (text != "" && text != "Create New Listing" && text != "Log In" && text != "Learn More") {
            let carElements = element.getElementsByClassName('rq0escxv')[0];
            let car_info = carElements.getElementsByClassName('aahdfvyu');
                            
            let car = {
              price: car_info[0].innerText,
              listing: car_info[1].innerText,
              sentence1: car_info[2].innerText,
              sentence2: car_info[3].innerText
            };
                            
            cars.push(car);
          }
        });
      }

      return cars;
    });

    data.forEach(e => console.log(e));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      await browser.close();
      console.log('closing browser');
    }
  }
})();
```

---

Update from the comment.

```
(async () => {
  let browser, page;
  let url = 'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/nyc/search/?query=cars';

  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 500 });
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 60000 });

    let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let cars = [];

      if (document.getElementsByClassName('sonix8o1')) {
        Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('sonix8o1')).forEach(element => {
          let text = element.innerText;

          if (text != "" && text != "Create New Listing" && text != "Log In" && text != "Learn More") {
            let carElements = element.getElementsByClassName('rq0escxv')[0];
            let car_info = carElements.getElementsByClassName('aahdfvyu');
            let splitText = car_info[1].innerText.split(' ');

            let car = {
              price: car_info[0].innerText,
              listing: car_info[1].innerText,
              sentence1: splitText[0],
              sentence2: splitText[1]
            };

            cars.push(car);
          }
        });
      }
      return cars;
    });

    data.forEach(e => console.log(e));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      await browser.close();
      console.log('closing browser');
    }
  }
})();
```

That returns:
[image: The output that is returned]

Comment: This worked i just tested it and it returned back a array object with information on cars. 

The first one looked like:
```{price: "$1,930\n$22,000", listing: "2018 Honda Accord Sport Sedan 4D", sentence1: "New York, NY", sentence2: "24K miles"}```

Comment: actually need the split the sentence returned by listing(2014 audi a6) as sentence1:2014 and sentence2 : audi